# How would I delete the first 40 characters from every line in a multilined string?

Tags: javascript

I have a string and I need to remove the first 40 characters off every line. You would have a line like this:

**9e600771af0eb709982673ca996dc632eacbd99c  refs/heads/branch0

87499732f46076c8c054ec91b0fa71d8a720d09e    refs/heads/branch1

bd274092d4126b023f7580aef30baf141ca8983b    refs/heads/branch2

e27cc492e1d146b12c24ffbe0b58cfe9ea114e26    refs/heads/branch3**

But it needs to be like this:

**refs/heads/branch0

refs/heads/branch1

refs/heads/branch2

refs/heads/branch3**

or eventually this:

**branch0

branch1

branch2

branch3**

Is this possible in JavaScript?

Comment: "every line"...I don't see any separate lines here. Of course you can use regex or substring to clean up the string though, yes. What have you tried?

Comment: `substr(40)` for a start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [RegEx](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) `/^.{40}\s/gm`. 
Here

1. `^.{40}` will take any `40` characters from the beginning.
2. `\s` this will match the following space character.
3. `gm` will search for the match globally and through multi-line.

**Working Code Example:**

```js
var str = `9e600771af0eb709982673ca996dc632eacbd99c refs/heads/branch0
87499732f46076c8c054ec91b0fa71d8a720d09e refs/heads/branch1
bd274092d4126b023f7580aef30baf141ca8983b refs/heads/branch2
e27cc492e1d146b12c24ffbe0b58cfe9ea114e26 refs/heads/branch3`;

str = str.replace(/^.{40}\s/gm,'');
console.log(str);

// And
str = str.split('\n').map(function(s){
  return s.split('/')[2];
}).join('\n');

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice and quick with a simple regular expression.

```js
let str = `9e600771af0eb709982673ca996dc632eacbd99c refs/heads/branch0
87499732f46076c8c054ec91b0fa71d8a720d09e refs/heads/branch1
bd274092d4126b023f7580aef30baf141ca8983b refs/heads/branch2
e27cc492e1d146b12c24ffbe0b58cfe9ea114e26 refs/heads/branch3`;

// replace the first 40 characters of each line with ''
let replaced = str.replace(/^.{40}/mg, '');

console.log(replaced);
```